# Restrict input in Vaadin IntegerField when typing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I have a simple `IntegerField` in Vaadin 14 with the following settings:

```java
final IntegerField delayField = new IntegerField();
delayField.setMin(0);
delayField.setMax(600000);
delayField.setStep(1000);
delayField.setHasControls(true);

binder.forField(delayField).bind(AppConfiguration::getNotificationDelay, AppConfiguration::setNotificationDelay);
```

Using the step controls it is not possible to enter values lower than 0 or higher than 600,000. But if I type a value directly, then values like -52 are possible. My understanding was that `setMin()` and `setMax()` also works for user input.

How can I automatically restrict the input to the min/max values?

- If the user types a value < 0, then the value should be set to 0.
- If the user types a value > 600,000, then the value should be set to 600,000.

Comment: This would require some JavaScript code but the question is what should happen if someone enters a wrong value?

Comment: I updated my original question.

Comment: Doesn't this invalidate the field, show an error and so does not propagate into the bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is even a simpler solution. Just change the value in the `ValueChangeListener`:

```
delayField.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        if (event.getValue() < 0) {
            integerField.setValue(0);
        } else if (event.getValue() > 600000) {
            integerField.setValue(600000);
        }
    });
```